# change color of svg icon component with angular

Tags: css, angular, components

Here beginner in typescript, more with css and first time playing with SVG.

I'm trying to make an heater svg icon that the four wave change color in function of the heater heating stage.

In the console log, it seem to work on the controller but I'm unable to display the color properly.

#### HTML:

```
<div>
  <svg width="20%" height="30%"  viewBox="0 0 1024 1024" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" class="icon">
    <g>
     <title>background</title>
     <rect x="-1" y="-1" width="1026" height="1026" id="canvas_background" fill="none"/>
    </g>

    <g>
    <title>Layer 1</title>
      <!--top line-->
      <path d="m910,782.001l-800,0c-8.837,0 -16,-7.163 -16,-16s7.163,-16 16,-16l800,0c8.837,0 16,7.163 16,16s-7.163,16 -16,16zm-800,112l800,0c8.837,0 16,7.163 16,16s-7.163,16 -16,16l-800,0c-8.837,0 -16,-7.163 -16,-16s7.163,-16 16,-16z" id="svg_5"/>

      <!--wave 1-->
      <path d="m29,844.001zm188.237,-149.935c-0.078,0.081 -0.145,0.169 -0.225,0.249c-0.048,0.048 -0.101,0.087 -0.149,0.135c-0.188,0.19 -0.37,0.384 -0.559,0.573l-0.036,-0.036c-6.289,5.554 -15.887,5.342 -21.902,-0.672c-6.014,-6.014 -6.227,-15.611 -0.672,-21.899l-0.036,-0.036c81.293,-81.282 81.293,-159.067 0,-240.35l0.708,-0.708c-93.799,-93.787 -93.799,-176.847 0,-270.634c6.253,-6.253 16.392,-6.253 22.645,0c6.253,6.252 6.253,16.39 0,22.642c-81.293,81.282 -81.293,144.067 0,225.35l-0.011,0.321l-0.696,0.386c93.484,93.472 93.787,190.818 0.933,284.679z" id="svg_1"/>
      <!--wave 2-->
      <path d="m218,843.001zm188.237,-149.935c-0.078,0.081 -0.145,0.169 -0.225,0.249c-0.048,0.048 -0.101,0.087 -0.149,0.135c-0.188,0.19 -0.37,0.384 -0.559,0.573l-0.036,-0.036c-6.289,5.554 -15.887,5.342 -21.902,-0.672c-6.014,-6.014 -6.227,-15.611 -0.672,-21.899l-0.036,-0.036c81.293,-81.282 81.293,-159.067 0,-240.35l0.708,-0.708c-93.799,-93.787 -93.799,-176.847 0,-270.634c6.253,-6.253 16.392,-6.253 22.645,0c6.253,6.252 6.253,16.39 0,22.642c-81.293,81.282 -81.293,144.067 0,225.35l-0.011,0.321l-0.696,0.386c93.484,93.472 93.787,190.818 0.933,284.679z" id="svg_2"/>
      <!--wave 3-->
      <path d="m426,843.001zm188.237,-149.935c-0.078,0.081 -0.145,0.169 -0.225,0.249c-0.048,0.048 -0.101,0.087 -0.149,0.135c-0.188,0.19 -0.37,0.384 -0.559,0.573l-0.036,-0.036c-6.289,5.554 -15.887,5.342 -21.902,-0.672c-6.014,-6.014 -6.227,-15.611 -0.672,-21.899l-0.036,-0.036c81.293,-81.282 81.293,-159.067 0,-240.35l0.708,-0.708c-93.799,-93.787 -93.799,-176.847 0,-270.634c6.253,-6.253 16.392,-6.253 22.645,0c6.253,6.252 6.253,16.39 0,22.642c-81.293,81.282 -81.293,144.067 0,225.35l-0.011,0.321l-0.696,0.386c93.484,93.472 93.787,190.818 0.933,284.679z" id="svg_3"/>
      <!--wave 4-->
      <path d="m631,843.001zm188.237,-149.935c-0.078,0.081 -0.145,0.169 -0.225,0.249c-0.048,0.048 -0.101,0.087 -0.149,0.135c-0.188,0.19 -0.37,0.384 -0.559,0.573l-0.036,-0.036c-6.289,5.554 -15.887,5.342 -21.902,-0.672c-6.014,-6.014 -6.227,-15.611 -0.672,-21.899l-0.036,-0.036c81.293,-81.282 81.293,-159.067 0,-240.35l0.708,-0.708c-93.799,-93.787 -93.799,-176.847 0,-270.634c6.253,-6.253 16.392,-6.253 22.645,0c6.253,6.252 6.253,16.39 0,22.642c-81.293,81.282 -81.293,144.067 0,225.35l-0.011,0.321l-0.696,0.386c93.484,93.472 93.787,190.818 0.933,284.679z" id="svg_4"/>        
    </g>
  </svg>
</div>
```

#### Script:

```ts
import { Component, Input, OnChanges } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'heater-svg',
  templateUrl: 'heater-svg.html'
})
export class HeaterSvgComponent implements OnChanges {
  @Input() stage: number = 0;

  constructor() {
  }

  ngOnChanges() {
    this.stageSet(this.stage);
  }

  stageSet(stagePercent: number) {
    let idList = ["svg_1", "svg_2", "svg_3", "svg_4" ];
    let stage: number = 0;

    if (stagePercent > 99) {
      stage = 4;
    } else if (stagePercent > 70) {
      stage = 3;
    } else if (stagePercent > 30) {
      stage = 2;
    } else if (stagePercent > 0) {
      stage = 1;
    }

    console.log(stage);  // <<<-----------------

    for (let i = 1; i < 5; i++) {
      let state = false;

      if (stage >= i) {
        state = true;
      }

      this.displayStage(idList[i-1], state);
    } 
  }

  displayStage(id: string, state: boolean) {
    let el = document.getElementById(id);

    if (el) {
      if (state) {
        console.log("fill in red");
        el.style.fill = '#ff3300';
      } else {
        el.style.fill = '#dadada';
      }
    }
  }
}
```

This is used in an ionic4 app, inside an ion-slide oc 10 slide:

```html
<heater-svg [stage]="channel.percentOut"></heater-svg>
```

`displayStage` fires and `console.log` logs the data correctly, but  `el.style.fill` does not work when I do not mute the else one, and even so, it only change the icon in the first slide...

Is component use some kind of instance for each use of the ccomponent or resource are some share?

Is `getElementById` a good way of doing it? Or is `fill` the better way to change the svg color? I think the data [stage] is processed correctly.

Comment: typescript has nothing to do neither with colors nor svgs. You are talking about the ionic app, where you first of all have Angular in place. Please learn it first. All your questions would be answered [here](https://angular.io/docs) after you pass the tour and docs. This particular question could be answered, but your problems are so basic, so I'd rather propose you start there

Comment: Hi @smnbbrv.  Like I pointed out, I,m a really beginner, but at first, an hobbyist. I only understand little thing of angular. In fact, most the time, I'm not sure if what I do is angular, typeScript, ionic or javascript related. This module is the last part of a larger project, and the doc for angular is very large. If you can at least pointing me out a cue to where to start... :P I tried to find somewhere something that does what I wanted to do without success.

Comment: ok... I get around component tutorial. Some question are more clear. But I cannot find the solution to my problem yet...  I tried `encapsulation: ViewEncapsulation.Native`, but then, getElementById did not work anymore...

Answer (score 1):

As suggested by @smnbbrv, I dig into angular, but also some css and sass rules...
Most of my problem was name scoping. I add to go trough getbyName instead of ById.

Also, I add to add and input to link the class instance to my data.

```
import { Component, Input, OnChanges } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'heater-svg',
  templateUrl: 'heater-svg.html',
})
export class HeaterSvgComponent implements OnChanges {

  @Input() id: number = 0;
  @Input('stage') stagePercent: number = 0;

  constructor() {
  }

  ngOnChanges() {
    let stage = this.getStageLevel(this.stagePercent);

    let els = document.getElementsByClassName('heater')[this.id];
    for (let i = 1; i <= 4; i++) {
      let state = false;      
      if (stage >= i) {
         state = true;
      }

      if (els) {
        let el = els.getElementsByClassName('wave')[i-1];//wave 0 is stage 1
        if (state) {
          this.setColor(el, '#ff3300');
        } else {
          this.setColor(el, '#dadada');
       }
      }
    } 
  }

  getStageLevel(percent: number) : number {
    let stage: number = 0;
    if (percent > 99) {
      stage = 4;
    } 
    else if (percent > 70) {
      stage = 3;
    }
    else if (percent > 30) {
      stage = 2;
    }
    else if (percent > 0) {
      stage = 1;
    } 
     return stage;
  }

  setColor(item, color) {
    item.style["fill"] = color;
  }

}
```